# String ist cutoff after first space character

Tags: string, xamarin.android, task

I have implemented a function that should output a string from inside a task. On most devices the output is correct but on only one device the string is cut off after the first space character.

```
public void WriteText(string text)
{ 
    activity_.RunOnUiThread(() => statustextview_.Text = text.Length.ToString() + text);
}
```

Example:

```
WriteText("STATUS: BETWEEN");
```

Output is 15STATUS:

The calculation of text.Length is correct but the string is cut off after the first space.

activity_ and statustextview_ are initialized inside the constructor.

Does someone have an idea what happens here?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Perhaps the next word ("BETWEEN") got moved to a new line, due to wrapping?.

Comment: Many Thanks! That was it. The missing text was hidden by the button below.